# New Monitor Attributes and Features

Tags: monitors, high-end

I am considering getting a new monitor over the holiday season. I mostly work in Photoshop, but also do some video editing. I also code (mostly Visual Studio and SQL).

I would love a curved monitor with loads of vertical and horizontal resolution so that I can split the monitor into four parts.

I am wondering what other attributes I should look for in a new monitor so that I may have the best setup?

Do any particular monitors come to mind?

Comment: you mention wanting both 4k and loads of resolution. But 4k is a specific resolution. I'd suggest updating the answer to either specifically wanting 4k, or if you're looking for an ultra wide for example.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, 4K curved monitors are always VA, but the best panel type for color accurate work is IPS/OLED. If you want OLED, you need a TV like the LG CX 48in (flat though) and if you want IPS, you need something like the AOC U2790PQU (also flat, and needs calibrating before doing color-accurate work).